# Neural network and information redundancy

Tags: neural-networks

Suppose I have a set of data described by the variables A and B.
The variable A by itself is not useful or not informative enough for a classification task. If I transform A, it describes the data better.

Now if we suppose that I apply 2 different transformations to the variable A (e.g., derivative and squaring function), I obtain new representations A' and A'' that can be interpreted differently. On the other hand, if I transform A and multiply it by B, I get another type of representative data that adds interpretability to the model.

Is it generally considered to apply these transformations/combinations to create some sort of "new" variables to train neural networks, or does it just adds information redundancy that we should avoid?

This question is from a non-expert.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind a neural network is that it will "learn" what functions it needs to apply to the input data in order to map it to the desired output. A' and A" contain all the same information as A, and if they are genuinely more descriptive of the data (the most useful representation to a human may not be the most useful representation to the network), the network will learn to apply that transformation on its own. However, if you know for certain that the network will find it easier to learn on the transformed data, then applying those transformations in preprocessing will decrease training time and could make the trained network more powerful.

So the final answer is: try it and see! Deep learning is very much an evolving science, so the only way to know for sure is to experiment.

Comment: exactly. The neural network will figure out the patterns between A and the output, no need for transformation.